# Passing data to contoller by ajax call-array of integers- MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
           $.ajax({
                url: '/Project/GetItemsBySearchKey',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchKey: "text",
                    exclussionList: [10,11]
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
```

I have this is  javascript and below function in c# MVC controller

```
public ActionResult GetItemsBySearchKey(string searchKey, List<long> exclussionList)
```

The value in the searchKey get in controller buT the exclussionList become null always
What is the error in my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set .ajax "traditional" property to true for shallow array [serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and default model binder for the mvc will do the rest.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Project/GetItemsBySearchKey',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    searchKey: "text",
                    exclussionList: [10,11]
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
```

And aciton will be:

```
public ActionResult GetItemsBySearchKey(string searchKey, List<int> exclussionList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass it as `string` instead of `array` and split it at controller

```
exclussionList: [10,11].join("-")
```